# Web Browser roadmap for HTML5 features?

Tags: browser, html5

I've been watching the caniuse.com site for a while now, and at one extreme we have Firefox releasing a new browser once/week (okay, slight exaggeration), and at the other extreme the Android list of 2.1/2.2/2.3/3.0/4.0/4.1/4.2 never changes. There is still nothing in the "Near future" or "Farther future" rows.

There are a number of HTML5 technologies not implemented even in 4.2, and I'm wondering when there is a new version coming, and what we can expect it to support. (EDIT: I'm looking for links to official announcements, developer blogs, etc. or a confident "nobody knows"; not speculation.)

(E.g. http://caniuse.com/eventsource )

(BTW, the StackOverflow Android tag seemed to suggest this was the best place to ask this kind of question. But if another site is better please let me know.)

Comment: I don't think this isn't the right site for your question. This isn't a problem you're having with your Android device. We don't have any more access to this information than you do. A new version of Android 4.x is rumored, but not confirmed, to be slated for release in the near future, but Stack Exchange isn't for idle speculation, either. You may want to have a look at http://developers.android.com and perhaps ask in the forums there.

Comment: I'd disagree, Al Everett; it is a question about the Android OS - the browser - so I think it's relevant, even if it is slanted towards web application development.  If the question was "When can I start viewing pages that use HTML5 features on my Android's  browser", it would sound more topical but be essentially the same question.

Comment: @Logos but you're not asking anything the Browser as it is now, which we could answer - you're asking about possible future directions of the Browser which would be purely speculation on our end, which isn't a type of question that fits.

Comment: I can see this as a borderline case. Since it's not _obviously_ off-topic, it seems fine to stay. It's still asking us to speculate, though.

Comment: @AlEverett, GAThrawn: I just edited my question to make it clearer I'm looking for announcements, or high-quality rumours (e.g. links to interviews with core developers), not speculation.

Answer (score 2):

[The default browser is being replaced by Chrome as of Android 4.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome#Development) for stock Android, so I doubt it will see any updates in the future.  If you want to use sites that have HTML5 features, you should install Chrome and use that (and by extension if you're targeting Android devices with a web app, you should be targeting Chrome).

Comment: Chrome may be the new default, but my Android 4.2 devices still have "Browser".

Comment: Thanks. Here is direct link to the reference quoted on the Wikipedia page: http://www.muktware.com/3779/chrome-out-beta-default-browser-android-41

Comment: According to caniuse.com (gs.statcounter.com), which I take with a pinch of salt, 4.0: 1.41%, 4.1: 1.34%, 4.2: 0.12%. Versus Chrome for Android on 0.6%. (firefox for android on 0.05%). So Chrome has perhaps 1 in 6 of the Android 4.x users.

Comment: Chrome is only the default browser on stock Android devices that came with 4.1, stock Android devices that did an OTA update to 4.1 (or 4.2) still have the Android Browser app. So, Nexus S, Galaxy Nexus, Motorola Xoom all of which are stock Android and have been OTA'd to 4.1 or 4.2 still have the default browser app. This means that there's a lot of stock 4.x devices not using Chrome by default.

Comment: @GAThrawn: true but irrelevant to the OP's actual concern, which is when will "Browser" get HTML5 updates.  The answer still is: probably never, as Google has switched to Chrome for the default browser *going forward*.

Comment: @Logos true, it's just that the way it was worded sounds like the problem with lack of updates will go away with 4.1 because everyone is moved over to the more frequently updated Chrome browser. I was just pointing out that this is a little optimistic and the problem with an un-updated Browser will be around for a bit longer, and it will need users to make a personal choice to (or be told to) move over to Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Dolphin Browser, and change the user-agent to ipad.

Then dolphin can use html5.

You see these instructions when you try to activate flash in Dolphin.